# How do you apply CSS to the editor iframe in jwysiwyg (jQuery wysiwyg)?

Tags: jquery, css, jwysiwyg

I'm using a slightly customized version of jwysiwyg for a website.

I'm trying to change CSS values inside the textarea replacement (the iFrame where the text gets written) - but I just can't seem to figure out how.  Do I have to create a new style sheet to apply to the iFrame?

Specifically, I want to change the iframe's :active and font: css settings.

Thanks,
Walker

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own CSS file with the built-in CSS option:

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg({css: "/otherStyleSheet.css"});
```

Just override the styles you want in that `css` file and you're all set, there are more examples on the [jwsiwyg intro page](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/wiki/Introduction).